# Blur underneath a <div> element

Tags: css

I have the following problem. I have a  element and want to blur just a part of it. An example is given below, where the main background is a  element

[image: video blurred partially]

In short, I want to blur the content underneath the `<div>` that has the blur filter.

I have checked and found how to do this for images (http://jsfiddle.net/ezaLot4d/), using the CSS :before selector. However, it is not valuable in my case, as my element is a video, so that the bluring should happen continuosly and not only when the page is rendered.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not worth it. Just use white 50% opaque or something. Creating blur over a video takes too much effort for a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check out BlurJS, a JavaScript Library that blurs whatever is underneath something.
http://blurjs.com/

You can use it like so:

```
$('.target').blurjs(options);
```

I've included the default options here:

```
{
    source: 'body',         //Background to blur
    radius: 5,          //Blur Radius
    overlay: '',            //Overlay Color, follow CSS3's rgba() syntax
    offset: {           //Pixel offset of background-position
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    optClass: '',           //Class to add to all affected elements
    cache: false,           //If set to true, blurred image will be cached and used in the future. If image is in cache already, it will be used.
    cacheKeyPrefix: 'blurjs-',  //Prefix to the keyname in the localStorage object
    draggable: false        //Only used if jQuery UI is present. Will change background-position to fixed
}
```

Comment: Definitely appropriate answer, it's worth noting that blur JS only works on background images. Someone did manage to do a blur effect using [CSS regions and filters](http://css-tricks.com/blurry-transparent-header-effect-ios7-css/), though the only browser that is supported in is Safari.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bjb568 nietonfir There are no essential parts to this answer. I am linking to a library, and even if I did post sample code here it will still become invalidated if the library was deleted. Please read my post before flagging it.

Comment: @KevinPei Well, hey, whadayaknow, maybe Stack Overflow doesn't allow library answers for that reason! Of course you can still post it as a comment, but **all link only answers are not an answer**.

Comment: @bjb568 First of all, **link only answers CAN be an answer**. If linking to a library that solves the problem isn't an answer, I don't know what is. Also, if you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, you'll notice that it says `Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.`. I believe saying where this link went is enough context. At any rate, I've added some documentation to end this dispute once and for all.

Comment: "Here's code that answers your problem that's in not-here!" That's Not An Answer, there's no context. But I appreciate the edit, dv retracted.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this with `backdrop-filter`:

```css
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
```

src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter